# is there an application to find identical parts in different files?

Tags: replace, copy-paste

i have a legacy HTML website I need to add some features to. Just looking at it, I noticed there are many "common" parts in each HTML file - footer, some script blocks, header, etc. I would like to move all these pieces into separate files (and include them using SSI for now) - that will make understanding of the project much easier. However, there are some blocks which looks similar but are a bit different (different class names for example). So straightforward cut/paste will not work - I will have to carefully examine each piece I remove. And I do not want to do that - there are too many files. I'm wondering if there is an application which can compare a bunch of files and find identical blocks (not necessary present in ALL files).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [clone detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code).

Many clone detectors will find only identical lines of code., or identical sequences of tokens.  Those won't work for you.   You want a clone detector that understands how to detect parameterized clones.

Some of the token-based detectors will find clones with only very minor variations as parameters; e.g., if it is *just* a class name which is different, these may work for you.  Such detectors often produce unstructured sequences of clones; the following is clone from the perspective of a token based detector:

```
   }   void  foo(
```

and

```
   }

   void bar(
```

To avoid such clones, token detectors generally insist on very long sequences of tokens, which means they can miss modest size but interesting clones.

Our CloneDR will find parameterized clones in which the parameter may be complex structure.  It does that by parsing the code of interest, and comparing the abstract syntax trees, which represent the essential code minus all the layout and whitespace.   Where the trees or sequences of trees are different, it can suggested a parameter representing the entire subtree (e.g., expression, htmt tag group, presence/absence of attributes, etc.).   Because it operates on trees, it CANNOT propose the kind of clone above.  That in turn means it can find modest size clones that make sense, as well as large ones.

CloneDR operates from precise language descriptions, to produce clones that precisely match language structures.   There is a version specifically for HTML.

(I'm the architect; you can see my technical paper on CloneDR at the Wikipedia page.)